# c# regex replace

Tags: c#, regex

Consider a string like this,

```
type="xxx.yyy.zzz, xxx.yyy, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

I read a resx file  and would like to replace all occurrences of the above string with String.Empty no matter what the Version is, but the version format will remain the same and the rest of the string does not change. I tried a few things but I'm in a bit of a crunch; and would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand: you want to replace the entire line with an empty string if it matches the version?  Or if it matches `xxx.yyy.zzz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type="xxx\.yyy\.zzz, xxx\.yyy, Version=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

- `\d` stands for a digit; `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- `.` is a special character and needs to be escaped as `\.`

As a c# regex string, it'd look like:

```
pattern = "type=\"xxx\\.yyy\\.zzz, xxx\\.yyy, Version=\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\"";
```

Comment: Hhm, what if there is a extra space or if version is only specified to x.x.x or if culture is not neutral. I know it is not your Regex there is faulty, but rather the question which lacks some information.

Comment: @lasseespeholt OP said _rest of the string does not change_ and I relied on that.

Comment: Yes, I know :) Again, I know your regex is not faulty. But will a extra space qualify for "a change"? <- question for Bala R

Comment: @lasseespeholt there won't be an extra space.

Comment: I'm now struggling with the Unrecognized escape sequence error. Will update once I get it to work.

Comment: oops - make all those \ to \\ - one for java, one for regex. See my update @Bala

Comment: I don't understand. why do I need the java regex string ?
in c# i tried replaciont \ with \\; that compiles but does not work.

Comment: @Bala C# or java, you need to escape backslashes in a string.